# OpenURI::HTTPError in ArticlesController#download 403 Forbidden - S3 - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I'm simply trying to allow my app to download files that are stored on s3. This seems straight forward but I keep getting this error `OpenURI::HTTPError in ArticlesController#download
403 Forbidden`

Here is my controller:

```
def download
    article = Article.find_by(id: params[:id])

    data = File.read(open("https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/theranostics-bucket/uploads/DMS-OctoberSocialMedia.pdf"))
    send_data data, filename: "file.pdf", type: "application/pdf", disposition: 'inline', stream: 'true', buffer_size: '4096'
end
```

It fails on the File.read line. What am I missing? I'm using Carrierwave to upload the files which is working just fine. It's only when I try to download I'm having issues.

Comment: Have you set the bucket permissions?

Comment: Have you find the solution?